# Get list of cities for specific country using latest Facebook search API

Tags: facebook

How can I get list of cities for specific country using latest Facebook search API. (For example: List of cities in United States)

The last time I able to get the city list from the below URL, which is no longer working

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?country_list['US']&type=adcity&list=global
```

---

This is how I retrieve all the country list

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=adcountry&limit=1000
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/targeting-search/v2.2#geo
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/targeting-specs/v2.2#location

IMHO it's not possible to get the *whole* list of cities. You can use something like

```
GET /search?type=adgeolocation&location_types=city&country_code=US&q=new+york
```

but as far as I know you cannot omit the `q` parameter, because otherwise this wil result in an error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I found out when I send a character in 'q' parameter, its giving the all city list.

[link](https://graph.facebook.com/search?q='a'&country_list=['US']&type=adcity&list=global)

It may be a bug.

Comment: It seems need an access token to retrieve the country/city, with the extended permission ads_read in v2.2.